# How to rotate image in react native

Tags: react-native

I was using [react-native-image-rotate](https://github.com/dgladkov/react-native-image-rotate) to rotate images but its no longer mantained, any idea what could be a good alternative.
ps: I am not using expo and I am using react-native v0.71.0

I tried [react-native-photo-manipulator](https://github.com/guhungry/react-native-photo-manipulator) and other packages but the build fails everytime.

Comment: Hey! Try to use [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker), maybe it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,  I ended up forking react-native-image-rotate and doing the necessary changes so it can work again.
The package you mentioned as far as I know is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @FirasBouadila could you open source the code you got?

Comment: @SergeiStralenia https://github.com/xtech-guru/react-native-rotate-image
you can run `yarn add react-native-rotate-image` to install the package

Answer (score 2):

Use [transform](https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms.html) style properties.

```
<Image
  style={{width: 50, height: 50, transform: [{rotate: '45deg'}]}}
  source={{
    uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
  }}
/>
```